# Pushing new versions of applications to RDP server

Tags: rdp, remoteapp

We have an application running as a RemoteApp on a 2008 RDP server. What is the proper way to push new versions of the app?

We don't currently have an msi for it, but we could make one.

Right now we just copy over the files, but that doesn't seem to be an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you might run into problems if there are registry files and expectations of different Windows system libraries involved.  Thus I don't think you'll be highly successful in packaging in this way.

Why can't you get the *.msi file or install from the vendor?  I hope you are acting ethically with respect to the restrictions on the programming from the vendor.

Comment: It's an internal application that we wrote, so no ethical issues. The main problem we encounter is that if someone is logged into server we can't update the executable because it's in use. What I'm looking for is a Best Practices.

Comment: Why not just use one of the various excellent packager programs out there?  I've seen excellent commercial versions, and I would imagine that with just a small amount of investment a free solution would be available.  (SE policy prevents any further specification of specific vendors).

Comment: The question isn't about how to package it. It would be very easy to create an msi using WIX. What I'm asking is how to roll that out to the server. I haven't been able to find a Best Practices for rolling out new versions of applications to RDP server farms. I would have thought that MS would have had some kind of functionality for it.

Comment: Best M$ practice seems to be using an *.msi file to add....and using a packager to generate it.

Comment: Best practice would say to install/update the application when users `aren't` logged into the server. That is what maintenance windows are for. If you don't have on you should schedule one.